# Making proper alignment of a div content in CSS

Tags: html, css

In my application, there is a view page where I'm showing a question along with its answers. Answers can be so long. Each answer would be preceded by a `radio button`. My answers' view is available here (http://jsfiddle.net/eN22Q/)

In that how I can achieve the below given style for an answer content:

> - MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD
>     MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD
>     MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD
>     MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MSD MS

Please help :)

Comment: Why voted for closing? Please comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a simple table work for you?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kG7rP/2/

**CSS**

```
td{vertical-align:top;}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
        </td>
    </tr>    

</table>
```

Comment: Its actually a `div` content I would like to align, not `td` and thanks for pointing out another option using `td`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add extra markup in your page then use css hacks like- make your input radio button `display: inline-block;` and add negative margin, `margin-left: -20px;`
In your case.

```
<input id="answer_id_195" name="answer_id" style="margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 2px;
float: left;
display: inline-block;" type="radio" value="195">
```

It will assume that the element stays there even if left its place. Hope this works for you.